# ant uptodate with single source file and multiple target files without name based mapping

Tags: java, ant

I have a build where a single protomsg source file generates multiple java files.
I want to check whether the files generated are uptodate wrt source file.

For a single target file it works, but it doesn't work if ***.java** is used. 
I need to check it with all files generated.

```
<target name="stub.uptodate.check">
   <uptodate property="stub.uptodate" srcfile="file.blah" targetfile="path/to/targetfiles/*.java"/>
</target>
```

A simple solution would be checking with a single file among them, but I can't use that now. I did not file any solution with mapper.

Answer (score 1):

There is `<outofdate>` http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html , which can handle multiple targets.